# Are Box-Cox and differencing redundant or complementary?

Tags: time-series, arima, data-transformation, differences, box-jenkins

I was always under the impression that differencing and Box-Cox were two ways to achieve the same goal: Making a time series stationary so that it can be modeled using an ARMA process.

However, looking at the code for auto.arima(), I notice that there is an option to include a Box-Cox transformation, which if my idea about redundancy is correct, doesn't make sense.

Now I am questioning whether that was correct to start with:

- Is it correct that Box-Cox and differencing are two means to the same end?
- If not, what does Box-Cox do exactly, since it seems that differencing already makes the time series stationary?
- Does the combination of ARMA + Box-Cox still count as ARIMA (based on the inclusion of Box-Cox in the auto.arima() function) - since the "I" is no longer necessary? Or does it count as an ARIMA-like approach, but not ARIMA strictly speaking?

Comment: Box-Cox transformations are used to transform variables, for ex. log, to get your variables in a "prettier" form. Differencing is done to make a series stationary. These two concepts are not necessarily related.

Comment: Box-Cox transformations are used to transform a series to make to make the variance stationary http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-to-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers. Differencing and arma is done to transform the series to make the expected value stationary

Comment: @IrishStat: does the order matter? Should I use a Box-Cox transformation first to stabilize the variance and then first-difference to stabilize the mean or vice versa? What is the best practice?

Comment: the preferred order is to deal with the expected value first. "ARIMA MODELS AND THE BOX-JENKINS METHODOLOGY" by MAKRIDAKIS & Hibon laid out the flaws of using differencing when linear detrending was more appropriate. If you can't find the paper send me an email and I will respond (dave@autobox.com_

Comment: When dealing with non-constant error variance be aware that untreated pulses  and other untreated latent deterministic structure can falsely suggest either Box-Cox or deterministic break-points.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461014/stochastic-vs-deterministic-trend-in-time-series MIGHT BE OF INTEREST